# strncpy_s error when deploying ffmpeg streaming application on XP

Tags: dll, ffmpeg, windows-xp, mingw32

I'm trying to deploy an application that uses ffmpeg to stream camera output to an XP machine. The application is written compiled with gcc mingw32 and runs fine on Windows 8. But on Windows XP I get the following error:

```
The procedure entry point strncpy_s could not be located in the 
dynamic link library msvcrt.dll
```

GCC command, excluding paths:

```
g++ -o mingw\streamer.exe src\testffmpeg.o -lavformat -lavutil -lavcodec -lFlyCapture2_C_v100
```

Dependency walker shows the following:
[image: Depedency Walker]

How can I work around this strncpy_s problem? It seems to be ffmpeg which uses this function is msvcrt. I used the windows binaries they provided. I'd rather not have to compile the library myself, as it has a huge set of dependencies.

Comment: You could just implement your own `strncpy_s` - it's a fairly trivial function.

Comment: How would I "tell" my application to use my implementation, and not to try to import the function from msvcrt.dll ?

Comment: On most operating systems the linker would just do the right thing but I don't know about Windows. You could try creating a dummy `strncpy_s` in your code to see if that resolves the link error and if it does then go ahead and implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Although not a generic solution, I solved this issue be using an older version of ffmpeg. The following release is the newest that does not require strncpy_s in msvcr.dll

- ffmpeg-20130706-git-63d7684-win32-shared
- ffmpeg-20130706-git-63d7684-win32-dev

As discussed in [this forum thread](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1291&p=5279&hilit=strncpy_s#p5279)

Answer (score 0):

Using ffmpeg-20130706 will work because it doesn't use the strncpy_s symbol instead of strncpy which is included in the runtime library. Unless the symbols you're using from ffmpeg have changed, you should be able to swap out the dlls wiht the ones from two weeks ago, otherwise, just recompile with the older dependencies.