# Windows shell: How can I get the audio device(s) name(s)?

Tags: windows, shell, audio, device

> I am not sure if this is strictly a programming question, as long as I
>   don't mind to use additional software in order to solve the problem, as long as it keeps being scriptable or command-line (this is: a not GUI solution). Anyway, I have posted another (a bit different) question at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/922008/windows-command-line-method-to-know-the-name-of-my-audio-recording-device). By the way, I will update here if I get the answer there.

My Windows program (just a shell script) **invokes VLC command-line** in order to **record audio** from the audio card and stream it out, like:

```
vlc dshow:// :dshow-vdev=none :dshow-adev="SoundMAX HD Audio I" :std{mux=ts,access=http,dst=:8080} :sout-keep [rest of the cmdline not relevant]
```

As long as there could be **multiple audio devices** on a computer (webcam, multiple audio cards, bluettoth devices... etc), I need to programmatically get the **name** of them.

I have used FFMPEG until now:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

... but sometimes it does not work OK, for example:

```
d:\Utils\FFMPEG\bin>ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
ffmpeg version N-72460-g11aa050 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --ena
ble-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 26.100 / 54. 26.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 34.100 / 56. 34.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[dshow @ 0000000000363520] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and
audio devices)
[dshow @ 0000000000363520] Could not enumerate video devices (or none found).
[dshow @ 0000000000363520] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 0000000000363520] Could not enumerate audio only devices (or none found
).
dummy: Immediate exit requested
```

The command line tool `SystemInfo` does neither work:

```
C:\>systeminfo | find "audio" /i

C:\>
```

Searching inside `regedit` found nothing about my soundcard example (`SoundMAX HD Audio I`).

Isn't there any other more reliable way to programmatically **obtain the sound device(s)** name(s)?

If possible, I would prefer to obtain answers for both Windows XP and Vista or later.

Additional **tests** performed:

- Installed latest MicroSoft .NET FrameWork v4.5.2 & rebooted.
- Tested older versions of FFMPEG: v4.8 (2014) and v4.7 (2013).
- Tested UAC elevated prompt.

Comment: I've never had FFmpeg fail to list Directshow devices.  I might suggest switching FFmpeg versions.  You might be missing a library or something.  Also, you might find a better answer for this over on SuperUser.com.

Comment: A curious result, @Brad : v4.8.2 and v4.7.3 (tested shared&static) have the same behavior on a Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate. But v4.7.3 solves the issue on Windows XP SP3. Extracted from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650354/strncpy-s-error-when-deploying-ffmpeg-streaming-application-on-xp

Comment: MSVCRT.DLL....  have you tried re-installing the Visual C++ Runtime?  Also, you might try getting your FFmpeg builds from somewhere else.

Comment: Well, @Brad, this is my location download for FFMPEG (seems official): http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/

Comment: Installed latest MicroSoft .NET FrameWork v4.5.2 & rebooted. Same results: `Could not enumerate audio only devices`, @Brad. Tested with FFMPEG v4.7.3 and latest v4.9.2. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try a 32-bit build.  I think DirectX is 32-bit only?

Comment: Same results: 32 bits yields can not enumerate audio devices neither. Tested v4.7.3 (2013) and latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer obtained (thanks, @Karan) from the above mentioned SuperUser thread.

Firstly, **FFMPEG should** return the device name value. If not, try:

- Update FFMPEG to latest version.
- Update .NET FrameWork.
- Try [another version](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). Note that v4.7.3 seems not to be needing .NET Framework, if this were the issue (extracted from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650354/strncpy-s-error-when-deploying-ffmpeg-streaming-application-on-xp)).
- For microphone devices make sure that the jack is connected. On some systems it seems the device is disabled (disappears) if not. Of course, this one does not apply to portables with embedded (built-in) microphone.

As a second option, only working (as for today, June 2015) for Vista and above, and not needing for the 30-40MB download of FFMPEG, you can try [SoundVolumeView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html) from NirSoft. Send values to .txt file and filter by doing:

```
SoundVolumeView /scomma Audio.txt
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %d in ('type Audio.txt ^| find "Capture"') do @echo Default recording device is: "%d"
```

As a third option, still for Vista and above, all the audio input (capture & recording) devices can be **extracted from the register** (explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/922178/268923) by @Karan) by issuing this command line:

```
for /f "tokens=9 delims=\" %a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture" /s ^| find "\Properties"') do @for /f "tokens=2*" %k in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture\%a\Properties" /v "{a45c254e-df1c-4efd-8020-67d146a850e0},2"') do @echo "%l"
```

Note: remember that when scripting such devices you can find **special localized characters**, like the spanish word `Micrófono` for `Microphone`. FFMPEG, for example, would show it as some rather strange `MicrÃ³fono`.

All the three above mentioned methods, including the NirSoft's, work fine on **remote console** (SSH, for example).

*Additional points*:

- Note that this answer solves the audio device name issue only for **recording/input/capture** devices, so (except for the FFMPEG case, maybe) the above methods are not valid or must be modified accordingly if you search for the playing ones.